# повторяющийся блок laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

на странице профиля у меня выводятся данные

```
    $shoolsubject = DB::table('user_subjects')
                ->join('shool_targets', 'shool_targets.id', '=', 'user_subjects.target')
                ->join('school_subjects', 'school_subjects.id', '=', 'user_subjects.shool')
                ->select('shool_targets.name as st', 'school_subjects.name as ss')
                ->where('user_subjects.user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
return view('profile.profile')->with(['profile' => Auth::user(), 'shool' => $shoolsubject->all()]);
```

данный код я поставил на открытие страницы, но если я редактирую профиль и страница перегружается, то выдает ошибку что не может найти переменную, которая выводит в шаблоне запрос , который выше

```
@foreach ($shool as $item)
     <div class="item">
            <div class="target">{{ $item->st }}</div>
            <div class="shool">{{ $item->ss }}</div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

и приходится в метод редактирования профиля опять пихать этот запрос, можно ли как то сделать, чтобы его не повторять 2 раза?

Comment: Может кто подсказать?

Comment: С примерами контроллера и маршрутов, которые отвечают за этот раздел, было бы проще ответить

Answer (score 0):

У Вас за эти действия отвечают два метода в контроллере, разные, как я понимаю, в одном в шаблон передаётся переменная $shool во втором нет, вот и ошибка. Вам нужно что бы эта переменная передавалась в шаблон и во втором методе + обверните цикл проверкой if

```
@if(!empty($shool))
  //Ваш цикл
@endif
```